# change color for seaborn horizontal bar chart

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a horizontal bar chart. It works but the color is in rainbow style. How to change the color for each bar to the same color?

```
%pyspark
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.clf()

sns.set_context("notebook", font_scale=0.5)

# plot barchart by x axis and use different color for day
sns.barplot(x = "scaled_importance", 
        y = "variable", 
        data = best_gbm_varimp[:10],
        orient = "h")

show(plt)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the parameter: [seaborn.barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html)

```
color: matplotlib color, optional

Color for all of the elements, or seed for a gradient palette.
```

> Used for visualization the sample example: [Horizontal bar plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/horizontal_barplot.html)
>
> Here is an example without **color** so result is "rainbow":

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Initialize the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 15))

# Load the example car crash dataset
crashes = sns.load_dataset("car_crashes").sort_values("total", ascending=False)


# Plot the crashes where alcohol was involved
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="alcohol", y="abbrev", 
            data=crashes,
            label="Alcohol-involved", 
            orient = "h")
```

[image: sample output with all the colors]

> Now we specify the **color='b'** #blue:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="whitegrid")

# Initialize the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 15))

# Load the example car crash dataset
crashes = sns.load_dataset("car_crashes").sort_values("total", ascending=False)


# Plot the crashes where alcohol was involved
sns.set_color_codes("muted")
sns.barplot(x="alcohol", y="abbrev", 
            data=crashes,
            label="Alcohol-involved", 
            orient = "h",
            color='b')
```

[image: with bars colored **blue**]